# Manually Release Googlemap Markers From MarkerCluster

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have too much markers on google maps about 15000.
so, I have Used MarkerClusterer For that.

Please do not down Vote.

Here is my Clustered Markers : http://jsfiddle.net/u758rqpa/45/

Here in my array first two markers have same latitude and longitude but they have different rotation angel.

when i click on these two markers cluster, that map is zoomed fully but not display those two markers.

And when click on other two markers cluster it display different.

I am not getting ,How can i display markers on MarkersCluster click.

so, is there any way to release markers from Markerclusters when i click on that ?

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: new google.maps.LatLng(markerA[i][2], markerA[i][2]),
              map: map,
              icon: {
                  path: 'm 32.460621,0.112468 -32.372233,-0.022 0,-0.088 L 0,0.090468 l 22.91468,22.9147 c 0.02205,-0.022 0.04437,-0.044 0.06629,-0.066 6.300656,-6.3007 9.451842,-14.5699 9.47965,-22.8263 z',

                  fillColor: color[i],
                  fillOpacity: 1,
                  strokeColor: '',
                  strokeWeight: 0,
                  rotation: 250 + markerA[i][3],
                  anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0)
              }
          });
     clustermarkers.push(marker);     
}
markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, clustermarkers);
```

Here is Another demo which is not clustering : http://jsfiddle.net/u758rqpa/47/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is an option in `MarkerClusterer` to do what you want:

`markerClusterer.setMaxZoom(MAX_ZOOM);`

Where `MAX_ZOOM` is the maximum zoom of your map minus one (in your fiddle, that would be 16).

This means that when the map is zoomed all the way in, the marker clusterer is no longer being used and the map displays all markers that are in the clusterer at the zoom level.

This method is listed in the [documentation for MarkerClusterer](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/reference.html)

Your fiddle with the `markerClusterer.setMaxZoom()` method: http://jsfiddle.net/u758rqpa/49/

Comment: can you please tell me how can i change MarkerCluster icon ?

Comment: @Nikunj - ask a new question.

Comment: Adam _ Here is My New Question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26294722/same-latitude-longitude-markers-display-at-different-places-in-google-maps